# Google Mobile Analytics Event Tracking: Multiple properties to describe an event in google analytics

Tags: mixpanel, google-analytics-firebase

In mixpanel, it is really easy to describe an event with multiple properties.

Is it even possible in google analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't store date from arbitrary JavaScript objects with Google Analytics events.

Each event is limited to [4 properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events): category, action, label and value.

So it is possible to describe an event with multiple properties, but it's very constrained.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, a GA event is limited to 4 properties : category, action, label and value.

But, you are free to declare [Custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets) in GA. You will be able to store different properties in those dimensions.

For example, if the user clicks on a chicken and you set a Custom Dimension "*Name of the chicken*" then you'll be able to give it with a value (say *Alfred*) with each event that you fire.

You'll query the custom dimensions as any other in the GA interface.

You don't have the same flexibility as you can have in Mixpanel though. The number of dimensions is limited to 20 by tracking property.